# Change Menu URL for custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, taxonomy, submenu

I have 2 custom post types and several custom taxonomies. Right now, I can manage these taxonomies under BOTH custom post types.

I want to stop that behavior and ONLY list the management links in a separate sub-menu.

When I hide the taxonomy by turning 'show_in_menu' false, and add the links under my Menu page, works, EXCEPT when you add a taxonomy, WordPress Admin doesn't "open" the proper Menu and Submenu - it defaults to the first Custom Post type.

In other words, right now, I have 2 Taxonomies (location and space) that have links to manage that appear under a "Settings" menu, but when I click on them, WordPress opens the page as if it's still located under the Custom Post type menu.

Is there a way to change this so that my Custom Taxonomy is managed under a separate Menu?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

Call the taxonomy management as the slug on submenu pages under the new menu page.

```php
add_menu_page(
    'Book a Room Complete Settings',
    'BaRC Settings',
    'manage_options',
    'barcomp-general-settings',
    [ $settings, 'barcomp_settings_page' ],
    'dashicons-admin-generic', 
    41.1
);
add_submenu_page(   'barcomp-general-settings', 
                     __( 'Manage Locations', 'barcomp' ), 
                     __( 'Manage Locations', 'barcomp' ), 
                     'barcomp_settings', 
                     'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=barcomp_location&post_type=barcomp_event', 
                     null
);

add_submenu_page(   'barcomp-general-settings', 
                     __( 'Manage Spaces', 'barcomp' ), 
                     __( 'Manage Spaces', 'barcomp' ), 
                     'barcomp_settings', 
                     'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=barcomp_space&post_type=barcomp_event', 
                     null
);
add_submenu_page(   'barcomp-general-settings', 
                     __( 'Manage Room', 'barcomp' ), 
                     __( 'Manage Room', 'barcomp' ), 
                     'barcomp_settings', 
                     'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=barcomp_room&post_type=barcomp_event', 
                     null
);
```

Then, find and change the parent and submenu files for the appropriate uses:

```php
add_action( 'submenu_file', function( $submenu_file ) {
    switch( get_current_screen()->taxonomy ) {
        case 'barcomp_location':
            $submenu_file = 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=barcomp_location&post_type=barcomp_event';
            break;
        case 'barcomp_room':
            $submenu_file = 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=barcomp_room&post_type=barcomp_event';
            break;
        case 'barcomp_space':
            $submenu_file = 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=barcomp_space&post_type=barcomp_event';
            break;
        
    }
    return $submenu_file;
});

add_action( 'parent_file', function( $parent_file ) {
    
    switch( get_current_screen()->taxonomy ) {
        case 'barcomp_location':
        case 'barcomp_room':
        case 'barcomp_space':
            $parent_file = 'barcomp-general-settings';
            break;
        
    }

    return $parent_file;
});
```